# Can QuickBooks SDK be used to work with WebConnector?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, quickbooks, qbxml

I need to integrate QuickBooks Desktop application with a Java web application. So no QuickBooks Online API will be used this time. Good old desktop with WebConnector and JAX-WS.
I had successfully passed through long way of setting up WebConnector to communicate with the application with JAX-WS.
Now I face the following question:

**What tool should I use in order to build QBXML requests and responses?**

For example I know that in order to let's say add a customer, the following QBXML should be returned in **sendRequestXML()** method (thanks to [Consolibyte examples](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Customer)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerAddRq requestID="Q3VzdG9tZXJBZGR8MTExMTIxMjE=">
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>Keith Palmer Jr.</Name>
                <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                <MiddleName></MiddleName>
                <LastName>Palmer Jr.</LastName>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>134 Stonemill Road</Addr1>
                    <City>Mansfield</City>
                    <State>CT</State>
                    <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                    <Country>USA</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <Phone>999-99-9999</Phone>
                <Email>test@example.com</Email>
                <Contact>Keith Palmer Jr.</Contact>
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>            
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

But should I use some third-party libraries like let's say [java-xmlbuilder](https://github.com/jmurty/java-xmlbuilder) to build this XML or are there any QuickBooks SDK built-in methods and classes?
I have added Java SDK's jars into the project and went through API. But there is no any manuals and tutorials so I still can't figure out whether SDK can help with this or it should be just used with Online edition?

Comment: Hi, I want to communicate with QuickBook desktop application using java application without web API. Can you share a sample code as i don't get idea how to connect and send request. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use the QuickBooks QBFC libraries, which are basically a set of .NET classes that serialize to qbXML.

With that said... it's probably not worth it since:

- You're using Java, not .NET (so you'd have to use JNI or something to bridge it over to Java)
- It's just silly easy to build XML in Java
- It's also really easy to use JAXB or JiBX or Castor to create your own native Java classes from Intuit's .XSDs

You should definitely look at the [QuickBooks OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) as well, which shows exactly what XML you can send for every single request QuickBooks supports.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've seen the OSR that is a definitely helpful resource and just wonder about a way to build these XMLs. So if I understand that correct, I should implement own XML building logic. I agree that it is not something difficult since I know exactly the structure of XML and can use various Java libraries for that. 
I just wondered whether Java SDK already had some of these to not reinvent the weel.
If not, then what the SDK is used for? I see there is class Customer, Invoice, QueryResult, so on. So how should they be used?

Comment: The Java SDK is only for QuickBooks ONLINE. It is not relevant to the Web Connector at all. Build your own XML, however you want.

Comment: Thanks, Keith! That's the answer I've been looking for.